# How to move the bibliography in markdown/pandoc

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, pandoc

I'm currently writing my bachelor thesis and my instructor wants me to put my appendix after the bibliography but markdown/pandoc puts the references at the end by default.
I read the instructions at http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/pandoc/ and tried to use the `include-after-body=FILE` command to put a separate .rmd file at the end of the document
My code looks like this:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(knitr)
pandoc('thesis.rmd', format="latex")
```
````

and for the options:

```
<!--pandoc
t: latex
include-after-body: appendix.rmd
o: output.pdf
-->
```

Where appendix.rmd is the separate appendix file.

After klicking on convert pdf, the process gets stuck with an error after the line 
`executing pandoc  --include-after-body=appendix.rmd -o thesis.pdf -f markdown -t latex -o thesis.pdf "thesis.utf8md"`

The error is:

`pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF from TeX source.`

Is there something wrong with the code or is there some other method to remove the bibliography from the end of the document?

Comment: Very interesting question, would like to do exactly the same!

Comment: Well it's been a while since I had the problem so maybe there is another solution but I used a workaround which is a bit messy but it did the job.
I first created a pdf without the appendix and the bibliography at the end and afterwards created another pdf which only contained the appendix, without page numbers and put the two pdf documents together.
I know it's not ideal but my thesis advisor was fine with it, so maybe it helps you as well.

Answer (score 20):

There is another solution:

```
<div id="refs"></div>
```

It lets you put the references wherever you want.

Comment: For me, this did the trick! Thank you! Note: it also works for docx.

Comment: I don't think this trick works with LaTeX output, as the OP seemed to want.

Comment: It also works for LaTeX, but not properly in combination with biblatex.

Answer (score 17):

You can place your bibliography wherever you like by inserting

```
::: {#refs}
:::
```

wherever you want the bibliography printed. From the ["Placement of the bibliography" section of the pandoc markdown manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#placement-of-the-bibliography).

For example:

```
...main body

# References

::: {#refs}
:::

# Appendix
```

Comment: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#placement-of-the-bibliography is probably a more accurate link to the documentation for what you are discussing.

Comment: Apparently this only works for certain styles ("If the style calls for a list of works cited, it will be placed in a div with id `refs`, if one exists"). For instance, the [eisvogel](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template) template does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that it works when you use a tex file, like `--include-after-body=appendix.tex`. I'm not an RMarkdown or Tex expert at all but I could imagine that it will only include the file after your main Rmd is already converted to a tex file using the default template.