# Adding figures and tables after bibliography in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, cross-reference

I want to add tables and figures after the bibliography in an R Markdown document. However, R Markdown documents will by default always add the bibliography to the end of the report.

Is there an easy way to add content to the document after the references?

### Attempted Solutions

A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148325/how-to-insert-appendix-after-references-in-rmd-using-rstudio) showed that there is a way to put the appendix after the bibliography in R Markdown. This appendix is a separate file and is added to the document with `after_body` in the YAML header. I tried 2 different possible solutions and none of them worked.

1. I tried to put my appendix in a different file, but I ran into the problem of losing my references in the main file, as all the appendices are cross-referenced in the body of the paper. All references turn to **??** once I put them in a different file.
2. I put all my figures and tables in a different file while also keeping them in the main file. Then, I used `results = "hide"` to hide them in the main file. The idea was to create 2 separate PDFs and to merge them. Unfortunately, when the figures are hidden, the references also turn to **??**.

### Additional information

- I am using the output format `bookdown:pdf_document2`
- My figures are created by an `.R` file and imported into my R Markdown file with `include_graphics()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rather than trying to include things in the after_body, you are better off just repositioning where the bibliography appears in the document. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44546963/7347699), you can choose where the bibliography appears using `<div id="refs"></div>`.

Secondly, you can use bookdown to easily add appendices within a document. Using the header `# (APPENDIX) Appendix {-}` will change all following secton numbers from numbers to letters. Check out the [bookdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#special-headers)

Used in a full example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: bookdown::pdf_document2
references:
- id: fenner2012a
  title: One-click science marketing
  author:
  - family: Fenner
    given: Martin
  container-title: Nature Materials
  volume: 11
  URL: 'http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nmat3283'
  DOI: 10.1038/nmat3283
  issue: 4
  publisher: Nature Publishing Group
  page: 261-263
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    year: 2012
    month: 3
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(magrittr)
```

# Introduction

Here is a citation [@fenner2012a]

# References {-}

<div id="refs"></div>

\newpage 

# (APPENDIX) Appendix {-}

# Appendix A

Here is your table

```{r table, fig.pos="H"}
knitr::kable(mtcars[1:5, 1:5], caption = "A table") %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position")
```
````

[image]

> **Note:** this will only work if you use pandoc's built-in citation package and won't work if you set  `citation_package: natbib` in the YAML

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it worked. But, for some reason, when I try it on my actual work, it's not working. And by "it", I mean `<div id="refs"></div>`. I have noticed that the main difference is that my references are contained within a `bib` file, which is imported via the YAML header meanwhile the reference in your example is directly inside the YAML header. Do you think this is what causes the issue?

Comment: I just removed the following line from the YAML header and it worked!

`citation_package: natbib`

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've altered the answer to highlight this. Also,  there is no difference between the way this loads the bib file: it just makes the example self-contained and easily reproducible

Comment: @MichaelHarper is there a way to do this without removing the citation package? I really don't want to use pandoc for the bibliography, as it doesn't look good... I have to enclose some pdf's as an appendix after the bibliography, but my reference list looks really ugly with pandoc. Suggestions?

Comment: What doesn't look good exactly? If you dislike the citation style you could change this by providing a different CSL file: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html#citation_styles . Not immediately sure of a solution though as I don't use natbib, sorry!