# Why does _output.yml prevent me from moving references in bookdown::pdf_book()?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

The top voted answer to this question, [How to move the bibliography in markdown/pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815781/how-to-move-the-bibliography-in-markdown-pandoc), says that you can control the location of the references in rmarkdown/pandoc by adding `<div id="refs"></div>` where the references are supposed to appear. This does not work in the pdf_book format from the bookdown package if _output.yml contains a pdf_book output. An example is a directory containing two files:

_output.yml

```
bookdown::gitbook:
bookdown::pdf_book:
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
  keep_tex: yes
```

index.Rmd

````
--- 
title: "An example"
author: "Me"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
bibliography: [packages.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
---

# Prerequisites

```{r include=FALSE}
# automatically create a bib database for R packages
knitr::write_bib(c(
  .packages(), 'bookdown'
), 'packages.bib')
```

I want references *here*

<div id="refs"></div>

# Introduction

We are using the **bookdown** package [@R-bookdown].
````

Calling `bookdown::render_book(output_format = 'bookdown::pdf_book')` creates a pdf file that has references at the end of the document, not at the location specified by `<div id="refs"></div>`. In contrast calling `bookdown::render_book(output_format = 'bookdown::gitbook')` does place the references at the specified location.

If I delete _output.yml or delete the pdf_book section,

_output.yml

```
bookdown::gitbook:
```

Then running `bookdown::render_book(output_format = 'bookdown::pdf_book')` does place the references in the correct location.

My package version info is:

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042), RStudio 1.4.1103

Locale:
  LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252   
  LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
  LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

Package version:
  assertthat_0.2.1  base64enc_0.1.3   bookdown_0.21.6   callr_3.5.1      
  cli_2.3.0         compiler_4.0.3    crayon_1.4.1      curl_4.3         
  desc_1.2.0        digest_0.6.27     evaluate_0.14     glue_1.4.2       
  graphics_4.0.3    grDevices_4.0.3   highr_0.8         htmltools_0.5.1.1
  jsonlite_1.7.2    knitr_1.31        magrittr_2.0.1    markdown_1.1     
  methods_4.0.3     mime_0.10         pkgbuild_1.2.0    prettyunits_1.1.1
  processx_3.4.5    ps_1.5.0          R6_2.5.0          remotes_2.2.0    
  rlang_0.4.10      rmarkdown_2.7.1   rprojroot_2.0.2   rstudioapi_0.13  
  stats_4.0.3       stringi_1.5.3     stringr_1.4.0     tinytex_0.29     
  tools_4.0.3       utils_4.0.3       withr_2.4.1       xfun_0.21        
  yaml_2.2.1
```

Why does having an otherwise valid _output.yml prevent me from changing the location of the references? Are there options I can add to _output.yml that will make pdf_book respect `<div id="refs"></div>`?

Comment: Crossposted to github, https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/1082

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the answer I posted on Github https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/1082#issuecomment-811026589

Changing placement of the bibliography using a div of id `refs` as explained in https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/bibliography.html#include-appendix-after-bibliography is a **Pandoc citation processor feature**. See https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#placement-of-the-bibliography

Using Pandoc's `citeproc` is the default for `pdf_document()` and `pdf_book()`, but here n your output file `_output.yml`, you are explicitly changing `citation_package` to `natbib` for the `bookdown::pdf_book` format.

When you call `bookdown::render_book(output_format = 'bookdown::pdf_book')`, depending on the case you tested, this will happen

- if the format is defined in `_output.yaml` it will use the configuration define there and use `natbib`
- if the format is not defined in `_output.yaml` it will use the default config for the format and `--citeproc` will be use.

You can only control the placement of the bibliography with a div of id `refs` in the second case.

You just need to change the `citation_package:` accordingly to want you need, and remove the field if you want to use Citations features from Pandoc processor.

Comment: for me  "citation_package: default" does not do the trick

Comment: Hi @OscarThees can you open a new issue in bookdown repo to share what issue you are encountering with information on your system (versions, OS, etc..) ? Thank you !