# Manual placement of bibliography in pdf markdown

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I have read through the answers on this post, but I can't get either of them to work (not overly surprising given that the article is over 6 years old now): [How to move the bibliography in markdown/pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815781/how-to-move-the-bibliography-in-markdown-pandoc)

They suggest:

```
::: {refs}
:::
```

and

```
<div id="refs"></div>
```

This is my yaml:

```
  output:
    bookdown::pdf_document2:
      keep_tex: true
      toc: true
      fig_caption: true
      number_sections: true
      citation_package: biblatex
  fontsize: 12pt
  geometry: margin=2.54cm
  header-includes:
    - \usepackage{leading}
    - \leading{18pt}
  bibliography: "../references/growthPotential.bib"
  csl: "../references/trends-in-ecology-and-evolution.csl"
  link-citations: yes
```

I have numbered sections throughout my document
1 - Abstract
2 - Introduction
...
7 - References
[this is where I want my references]
8 - Tables & Figures

But by default the list is added, un-numbered and unlinked at the very bottom of the document. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is taken from R Markdown Cookbook by Yihui Xie.

By default, the bibliography appears at the very end of the document. However, there can be cases in which we want to place additional text after the references, most typically if we wish to include appendices in the document. We can force the position of the references by using , as shown below:

```
# References
<div id="refs"></div>
# Appendix
```

Although  is an HTML tag, this method also works for other output formats such as
PDF.

Comment: As explained in the original post, this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When faced with the similar issue, removing the citation  specification (`citation_package: biblatex` in your case) helped me.
If that does not work, you may try specifying an alternative citation package, e.g., `citation_package: natbib`.
Then, hopefully, the HTML-tag method will take an effect.