# How to insert appendix after references in Rmd using Rstudio?

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc

I am using Rstudio, to create a pdf / html document from an Rmd file. The header looks sth like this:

```
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
bibliography: bibliography.bib
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
```

Now, I have some sections, and then include the references. After that, an appendix should follow, but I encounter the exact same problem as described here: [Pandoc insert appendix after bibliography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427637/pandoc-insert-appendix-after-bibliography)

There is a fixed solution in this thread, but I have no idea how I can do that within RStudio directly. To get the document, I just press the "Knit html" button, and do not run any pandoc commands myself. So where should I put the

```
--include-after-body
```

part, and how should the appendix rmd file look like?

Answer (score 8):

As noted in the [rmarkdown manual](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/markdown_document_format.html#advanced-customization), you could use this syntax:

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    includes:
      after_body: appendix.md
---
```

This is equivalent to the general way to add arbitrary pandoc arguments to a Rmd file:

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    pandoc_args: ["--include-after-body=appendix.md"]
---
```

Comment: You can also add pandoc flags / options that are not covered by the yaml syntax. This is discussed in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427637/pandoc-insert-appendix-after-bibliography. It seems like the R markdown folks have introduced after_body includes lately or it is not well known. However, it might just be a more flexible (but more complicated) alternative.

Comment: You are right, I wasn't technically answering the OP's question about where to add a pandoc argument and it might be useful. I tend to prefer Rmd YAML options when they exist though, as they usually look better.

Comment: what if i am kniting a pdf document, how do I do this

Comment: @Keniajin the same solution should work, just replace html_document with pdf_document

Answer (score 3):

The following might be easier; works if you knit to PDF, Word or HTML:

```
Everything I wanted to say in the main document.

# References

<div id="refs"></div>

\newpage
# Appendix

Some details that will bore the readers of the main document.
```

In the original post, this was also posted as an answer (few years after current question was asked): see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44294306/8234333 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/16428699/8234333

Comment: Great solution. Clean and simple *and* also works in Quarto!

Comment: Very useful to contain source in one file only.

Comment: This no longer seems to work for me :(. The references are still appended after the appendix.