# Include Rmd appendix after references

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

My question is linked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148325/how-to-insert-appendix-after-references-in-rmd-using-rstudio) one. I wish to include my appendix after my references so I am using the `after_body` tag in my yaml, however I need to be able to `knit` my `appendix.Rmd` file. I have tried the following:

```
after_body: "`r knitr::knit('appendix.Rmd')`"
```

however this attempts to knit the `appendix.Rmd` file before the actual report and therefore fails as it does not have the required libraries or objects in memory.

Comment: One work-around would be to manually generate the references section using something like the `bibliography()` function from [knitcitations](https://github.com/cboettig/knitcitations).

Comment: If appendix.Rmd is reliant on libraries and objects generated by the .Rmd file you want to append it to, you will always have dependency issues. When you knit an .Rmd file it is run in its own, insulated environment (ensures reproducibility). Thus any libraries attached or objects generated when knitting a document will not be available to another .Rmd.

Comment: Yeah I know that. But it must be possible to run it afterwards surely?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In order to have appendices *after* the references, you simply include a div with id="refs" which tells pandoc where to include the references section. For example:

````
```{r, child = "08_discussion.Rmd"}
```

# References

<div id="refs"></div>

```{r, child = "09_appendix.Rmd"}
```
````

Credit: https://twitter.com/tjmahr/status/763435602935095296

Comment: This doesn't work when using `natbib`.