# Error when reading md/tex/Rmd file while compiling a Latex document in Rmarkdwon

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am trying to add one or more appendix pages after my references when using Latex in Rmarkdown. After trying the solutions in "[Pandoc insert appendix after bib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427637/pandoc-insert-appendix-after-bibliography)" and "[Insert Appendix after references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148325/how-to-insert-appendix-after-references-in-rmd-using-rstudio)" I get an error that doesn't make any sense to me because the solution it provides it has to do with numeric types (which I am not dealing with?).

My header:

```
---
title: "A smart title here"
author: "Ashameed Person"
geometry: margin=1in
header-includes:
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \AtBeginDocument{\let\maketitle\relax} #to hide title
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: no
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_bib: yes
    toc_depth: 2
    citation_package: natbib
    pandoc_args: ["--include-after-body=appendix.md"]
fontsize: 12pt
bibliography: WorkCited.bib
biblio-style: humannat
link-citations: true
---
```

My Rmd file:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, eval = TRUE)
```

```
\section{new section}
A lot of gibirish \citep{scottdamblon2010, hirth2010}.
See appendix for more info.
```

When compiling my document I get the following error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
                $
l.142   bookdown::pdf_
                      book: 

Try to find the following text in Draft1.Rmd:
  bookdown::pdf_ 

You may need to add $ $ around a certain inline R expression `r ` in Draft1.Rmd (see the above hint). See https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/385 for more info.
Error: LaTeX failed to compile Draft1.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Draft1.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

My [appendix.md](https://github.com/roldaj5/StackOverflow-Question/blob/06e852bd0ccd8f3028c4b9ac568e6f49a5f7fbdc/appendix.md) is similar to that of the above and it looks like this:

```
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: no
    citation_package: natbib
fontsize: 12pt
link-citations: true
---

\section{Appendix B - Raw Data}
\newpage
Raw data can be found at some repository
```

I have also tried to use the file extension .Rmd and .tex instead of the .md found at after the argument `pandoc_args:`. In addition, I have tried to change `pandoc_args:` with `includes: after_body: appendix.md` but this compiles my pdfbook but does not add the appendix section.

You can find my [references](https://github.com/roldaj5/StackOverflow-Question/blob/master/WorkCited.bib), [my orginal rmd](https://github.com/roldaj5/StackOverflow-Question/blob/master/Draft1.Rmd), [humannat file](https://github.com/roldaj5/StackOverflow-Question/blob/master/humannat.bst), and [appendix file](https://github.com/roldaj5/StackOverflow-Question/blob/06e852bd0ccd8f3028c4b9ac568e6f49a5f7fbdc/appendix.md), in these github's link.

Comment: Can you rework this into a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am new to posting and coding, I hope this addresses the issue

Comment: For some reason, latex is attempting to compile `pdf_book`. Try to reproduce this problem using the fewest lines of code possible. One approach to doing this is simply deleting all the lines that do not cause this error.